# No Grub After Windows Shutdown

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint, grub, bootrepair

I'm using ASUS Rog with Dual Boot (Windows 10 and Linux Mint). After windows shutdown, my system is not booting into any operating system; Shows a bios menu instead. I have tried to repair it using boot-repair on Live USB but still not booting into any operating system. My Boot-Repair Log is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3cpwMRQ92W/)

Any Help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had one operating system modify the disk of the other one? This can cause a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

Because neither Linux Mint nor Windows 10 boots properly you need a tool that can repair the bootloaders of both OSs. [Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) is a free bootable live CD/USB that can repair GRUB and the Windows bootloader. Rescatux has a graphical interface with a menu of operating system rescue tasks. If your hard disk has the MBR partitioning format, you can select the *Restore Windows MBR (BETA)* option to repair the Windows bootloader. If your computer has UEFI firmware, you can select among the UEFI boot options.

**Boot options:**

- (>=0.41 beta 1) Update UEFI order
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Create a new UEFI Boot entry
- (>=0.41 beta 1) UEFI Partition Status
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Fake Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Hide Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Check UEFI Boot

**GRUB options:**

- (>=0.40 beta 11) Easy GNU/Linux Boot Fix
- Restore GRUB and GRUB2
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Update any GRUB2 menu
- Update Debian/Ubuntu GRUB menus

**Windows options:**

- Restore Windows MBR (BETA)
- Clear Windows passwords
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Promote a Windows user to Administrator role
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Unlock Windows user

**Password options:**

- Change GNU/Linux Password
- Regenerate sudoers file
- Clear Windows passwords

[image]
<sup>**Rescapp is a nice wizard that will guide you through your rescue tasks.**</sup>

If Rescatux repaired the Windows bootloader but Linux Mint still can't boot, here is how to repair the Mint bootloader.

1. Check if the command `sudo fdisk -l` is able to find the Windows partition. In the results of `sudo fdisk -l` your boot partition is indicated by a * character.
2. Run `sudo update-grub` to update the GRUB bootloader and correct incorrect entries.

   ```
   sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
   ```